# Mongo DB error on bulk insert - The paging file is too small for this operation to complete

Tags: mongodb

We are having this issue while inserting a bulk records(5000) in mongo db. It is giving the below message and mongodb is getting stopped automatically. Error stack is,

> `2015-05-08T02:02:34.227-0700 [conn4866] insert DEV_TEST.STAGING_SKU_INFO inserted:5000 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:105336 105ms
>   2015-05-08T02:02:34.227-0700 [conn4866] VirtualProtect for D:/mongodb_data/DEV_TEST.0 chunk 4776 failed with errno:1455 
>   The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. 
>   (chunk size is 44040192, address is 4aa1600000) in
>   mongo::makeChunkWritable, terminating
>   2015-05-08T02:02:34.227-0700 [conn4866] SKUVIEW_DEV_TEST.SKUVIEW_SEQUENCE Fatal Assertion 16362`

Please let us know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: This question is better suited for DBA StackExchange as it is about database administration rather than programming. As per the [MongoDB production notes on Windows](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#configure-windows-page-file-for-mmapv1), if you are using the MMAP storage engine the recommendation is to use a fixed page file size of at least 32GB. Dynamic or insufficient page file sizes can result in abrupt server shutdown with VirtualProtect error 1455.